# On-The-Fly ModelBuilding

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, buffer

I am wondering to change and alter a model on the fly.

I have a whole process( model for the rest is done) that relies on different settings for buffers, and what I am trying to do is after I am not satisfied with the result of X buffer, I would like to go into model builder, and just change the value, and re-do the process, without needing to make a billion different confusing buffer files.

I have looked into erase, and append, but there are no tutorials on how to use erase and append, but from what I have seen, there should be a way:

Upon Starting up, the model erases any previous buffers, and appends the new settings to the same layer.

is this possible the way I imagine it?

Comment: So, the output data of your model is a single feature class that represents the analysis' results (buffering). After running the model and exploring the results in ArcMap, you are not satisfied with this and want to re-run the model using another input parameters' values (e.g., another buffer distance). Is it correct? If so, the only thing you need is just to allow the model to overwrite an existing feature class each time it runs. This will not create any additional data.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, so you want to 1. set buffer value automatively and 2. erase old files when model starts?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov It looks like the content from your comment may form an acceptable answer with not much more than a copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the output data of your model is a single feature class that represents the analysis' results (buffering). After running the model and exploring the results in ArcMap, you are not satisfied with this and want to re-run the model using another input parameters' values (e.g., another buffer distance). The only thing you need is just to allow the model to overwrite an existing feature class each time it runs. This will not create any additional data.